# How to connect to PC running VPN on the same home network

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn

I have a home network of several PCs all running Windows 10. One has a PIA VPN installed. There are two network adapters on that PC: the default one and the PIA.

I want to make sure if this VPN is down the internet traffic will not switch to the second (default) network adapter.
I tried to disable the default adapter but have immediately lost my Remote connection to this PC. I tried to use in RD the PC's name and the IP - nothing worked.

Any advice on how I can set this PC up so that it can have only a PIA network adapter? I also need to remotely connect to this PC from another PC on the same home network.

Comment: two physical adapters with physical plugs? the PIA adapter is a virtual adapter, so it isn't physical hardware, but it needs to use the physical hardware in order to carry a connection. My hunch is you have one network adapter, and are seeing two in the control panel. if that is the case, you need both. as for your root concern, you need a kill-switch. see here for PIAs support doc on kill-switches: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/blog/understanding-a-vpn-kill-switch/

Comment: Exactly. I have just one physical plug, so the PIA is a virtual. My killswitch on PIA failed once and the traffic switched to the default adapter. I would like to avoid this, but see that other than killswitch there is nothing I can do.

Comment: I wrote a shell script and scheduled it to run ever 30 seconds, which checks the status of the tunnel, attempts to reconnect if down, and stops selected services if it won;t come back up. And if it comes back up later, it will restart everything too. best I could do.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to disable the physical adapter, because the VPN virtual adapter relies on it.

VPN Tunnels are not magic; they are just packets containing packets. The outer packet is the vpn tunnel, and the inner packet is the payload passing through. So, in order for the VPN to work, you must have a physical nic online with an IP address for your LAN, a default gateway (the interior of your home router) and DNS servers configured. your box must be able to send and receive traffic to and from PIA in order to start the tunnel in the first place, and will always carry both the outer and inner packets.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.